# Как организовать систему личных кабинетов покупателей

Tags: php, modx

Всем привет!
Делаю портал. По аналогии с сайтом envato (https://market.envato.com/).

У каждого пользователя, который зарегистрировался есть целый набор страниц, на которых он может смотреть свои товары, статистику, настраивать аккаунт и загружать товары.Много чего.В общей сложности 15 разделов. На одного пользователя.

Я сделал авторизацию и регистрацию на office. Проблема в том, что мне нужно, чтобы пользователи (они же авторизованные продавцы) или незарегистрированные клиенты могли заходить на публичные страницы других пользователей (зареганных продавцов).

**Вопрос: Как тогда сделать создание аккаунта при регистрации? и как дать возможность просматривать страницу профиля?**

Потому как сейчас страница профиля наполняется данными авторизованного в данный момент юзера. И другой юзер на этой странице увидит только свои данные.

На одном портале с малым количеством пользователей я делал ресурс контейнер, который наполнялся подпапками с именем юзеров, подтвердивших регистрацию. И уже внутри этих папок юзеров я делал набор страниц, наполняемых данными только этого юзера. Таким образом я мог посмотреть публичные данные и блог любого юзера.
Здесь же подразумевается море пользователей и этот подход, думаю просто убъет и админку и вообще дальнейшую работу с пользователями.
Ребята, дайте совет

Answer (score 0):

```
Потому как сейчас страница профиля наполняется данными
авторизованного в данный момент юзера. 
И другой юзер на этой странице увидит только свои данные.
```

Вы же сами ответили на свой вопрос. Нужно добавить условие, в котором проверять, кто заходит на страницу:

Гость (нет сессии или идентификатора) - подтянуть данные владельца страницы (запросить из БД)

Юзер-владелец - подтянуть его данные

Другой юзер - запросить по адресу страницы настоящего владельца и подтянуть на страницу его данные.

Где конкретно делать эту проверку сильно зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения. Это может быть и отдельный класс, регулирующий права доступа, или конструктор класса, ответственного за отображение страницы.

Comment: А нет никакого юзера-владельца. Страницы общие для всех, данные просто заменяются в зависимости от того,кто из авторизованных смотрит эту страницу.